# Does WSO2 G-registry enable us to add stored procedure as one of the assets?

Tags: stored-procedures, wso2, registry, wso2-governance-registry

Can we add stored procedures into the Governance registry? Does G-reg supports that asset type? Because I could see, we can add wsdl, wadl, SOAP, REST services, Schemas and WS-Policies but my business requirement is to add stored procedures and AIP's into G-registry.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to achieve this using a registry extension(.rxt) to store the stored procedures which is similar to storing custom types of data such WSDLS, services etc. You can refer the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48284982) to get an idea from creating the registry extension file with the data model, deploy it in GREG and how to add a menu item to the custom registry extension file to be shown in publisher.